# Работа фильтра catalog smart filter в Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Скажите, кто в курсе - как фильтр заставить смотреть в цену за одну единицу товара в расширеном типе цен?

У меня в шаблоне выводится `$minPrice['PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE']`. Как мне использовать только это значение в фильтре?

Answer (score 1):

В настоящий момент никак. Фильтр не умеет работать с ценой со скидкой.

Путём доработок обычно делаю:

1. Создаю свойства MIN_PRICE и MAX_PRICE типа число (для сортировки и фильтрации)
2. Отслеживаю изменения цены (при изменении товара и агентом если есть интеграции)
3. В фильтр вывожу минимальную цену.